# FindMinimum with many Sums and NIntegrates is very slow

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, summation, procedural-programming, iteration

I want to calculate the global minimum of an equation which has several hundred `Sum`s (I used 300 in this code), but the calculation is very slow.

My code is as following. First, I define some initial parameters:

```
nc=3; lm = 680;m = 4.552;gs = (1.860/lm^2);qu = 2/3; qd = -1/3; p = 1; n = -1;
q[n_] := n; s[n_] := n; k[kf_] := kf; ku = 0.0*1/10^3; kd = 0.0*1/10^3;
eB = 0.01*10^6; t = 0.0001; ln = 10;
```

Then I define some functions:

```
M[a_] := m + a;
en[qf_, l_, sp_, a_, kf_] := Sqrt[p3^2 + ((Abs[q[qf]*eB]*(2*l + 1 - s[sp]*Sign[q[qf]*eB]) + (M[a])^2)^(1/2))^2];
f[qf_, l_, sp_] := lam^6/(lam^6 + (Sqrt[p3^2 + Abs[q[qf] eB] (2*l + 1 - s[sp] Sign[q[qf]*eB])])^6);
cd1[l_, a_, mu_] := NIntegrate[2/(4 Pi^2)*((en[qu, l, p, a, ku]*f[qu, l, p]) + t*Log[1 + Exp[-(en[qu, l, p, a, ku] + mu)/t]]), {p3, 0, ln*lam}];
cd2[l_, a_, mu_] := NIntegrate[2/(4 Pi^2)*((en[qd, l, n, a, ku]*f[qu, l, n]) + t*Log[1 + Exp[-(en[qd, l, n, a, ku] + mu)/t]]), {p3, 0, ln*lam}];
it=300;(*300 sum loops*)
veff[a_, mu_] := a^2/(4 gs) - nc*Abs[q[qu]*eB]*(Sum[ cd1[l1, a, mu], {l1, 0, it, 1}]+Sum[ cd2[l2, a, mu], {l2, 0, it, 1}]);
```

Lastly, I calculate the results with `FindMinimum`:

```
Do[
 Print[mu];
 lal = FindMinimum[veff[al, mu], {al, 100}]; 
 dm[mu] = M[al /. Last[lal]];
 alp[mu] = al /. Last[lal]; 
 vf[mu] = First[lal], {mu, 0, 700, 1}]
```

Currently, this takes long time for each iteration. How can we speed up this `Do` loop and `FindMinimum`?

Comment: Your `()` and`[]` don't seem to match up in `cd1` and `cd2` and I can't guess how to fix that. Scrape those off the screen, paste into notebook and look for little red characters hinting that there is a problem.

Comment: Yes , I corrected it.

Comment: Do you have bounds for your search space for the minimum?  With `a = 0`, `veff[a,mu]` will go to negative infinity as `mu` goes to negative infinity. The `a=0` part is not even necessary. For any finite `a`, `veff[a,mu]` goes to negative infinity as mu goes to negative infinity

Comment: Since `Abs` and `Sign` often make things more difficult for integration and minimization... I modified the definition of `f` to print `q[qf] eB>0` each time before calculating the result of `f`. I get a vast long stream of `True` printed, but I can't yet be certain this is ALWAYS true. Can you check and if this is always true then time your code with and without simplifying using this information?  Likewise your other `Abs` Next can you replace `q[qf]` with just `qf` and time it to see how much that helps if any? Likewise `s[sp]` Be careful with timing to do a fresh restart every time.